# PyOpenGL-accelerate + numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pyopengl

I'm installing [MakeHuman](http://www.makehuman.org/doc/node/overview_of_os_specific_installations_and_build_procedures.html) on Debian, so all dependencies was set up, but when launching it's an error:

```
SYS.PLATFORM: linux2
PLATFORM.MACHINE: x86_64
PLATFORM.PROCESSOR: 
PLATFORM.UNAME.RELEASE: 2.6.32.26
PLATFORM.LINUX_DISTRIBUTION: debian 6.0.6 
NUMPY.VERSION: 1.6.2
OpenGL_accelerate module loaded
Using accelerated ArrayDatatype
Unable to load numpy_formathandler accelerator from OpenGL_accelerate
Unable to load registered array format handler numeric
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makehuman.py", line 310, in <module>
    main()
  File "makehuman.py", line 300, in main
    from mhmain import MHApplication
  File "./core/mhmain.py", line 32, in <module>
    import mh
  File "./lib/mh.py", line 29, in <module>
    from glmodule import updatePickingBuffer, grabScreen, hasRenderSkin, renderSkin
  File "./lib/glmodule.py", line 33, in <module>
    from OpenGL.GL import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenGL/GL/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from OpenGL.raw.GL.annotations import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenGL/raw/GL/annotations.py", line 40, in <module>
    'v',
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenGL/arrays/arrayhelpers.py", line 197, in setInputArraySizeType
    function.setPyConverter( argName, asArrayTypeSize(type, size) )
  File "arraydatatype.pyx", line 393, in OpenGL_accelerate.arraydatatype.AsArrayTypedSizeChecked.__init__ (src/arraydatatype.c:7688)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sizeof'
```

Does anyone solve problems with link PyOpenGL+ numpy?

Comment: I suspect you probably need a newer version of numpy

Comment: Added NeuroDebian repository and reinstall numpy, but id didn't help. The same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed that on my system by issuing:

> sudo easy_install -U PyOpenGL

Noting:

- using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, with python2.7
- did get a Permission denied error without that leading 'sudo'
- via: http://matthew-4gl.wikispaces.com/python_modules ( in turn from  https://bitbucket.org/ompl/ompl/issue/59/problem-with-ompl_apppy )

good luck

Comment: It worked for me too, what's causing this issue? Even up to 5 years later?